# What folder structure should I use for the .dll files that I need in creating a Nuget package for both x86 and x64?

Tags: nuget

I am trying to write a Nuget package that has 3 .dll files for x86, and 3 for x64. I have my .nuspec file written, but I'm not sure what folders I should put my .dll files in. It needs to work on Windows 7, 8, and 10, and I am targeting .NET 4.6.2.

I have tried multiple different folder structures, such as lib -> net462 -> x86 x64 and win10-64/ win10-86, but I can't ever get it to quite work right.

After building my solution with the Nuget package, the .dll files should get put in the BuildOutput folder, under either the x86 or x64 folder.